# Deserialize object with DataContractJsonSerializer and map it to a list

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm already knew how to deserialize a JSON array using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, but now I have a JSON **object**, it has a key called `items` and the value is an `array`.

for example, the JSON string is `{ name: "someString", items: [1, 2, 3] }`

Now I want to know is there any built-in method to convert this object to a custom class derived from `List<T>`, for example to the following class:

```
[DataContract] // This is not working, you can't apply DataContract attribute to a List<T>
// [ItemsCollectionIsIn("items")]
public class MyObject : List<int>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name;
}
```

I had tried `[CollectionDataContract]` attribute with its `ItemName` set to `"items"`, but seems `DataContractJsonSerializer` just ignores `ItemName` property and serializes/deserializes the object to/from an array.

Now I can implement `IList<T>` on my class and return values from a internal list, or I think I can write one class for JSON object contract and the other one derived from List then populate values manually, is there any better ways?

I'm working on Windows Phone `LongListSelector` so I need a GroupedList (`List<List<T>>`).

Or if JSON.Net can do it more easier please give me some hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think you modeled your type incorrectly, the array is a property in the root object. Try it this way:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name;

    [DataMember]
    public List<int> items;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is some way to _map_ content of `items` to the object itself.

Comment: @SimonChan I don't know really. You can easily extract it with LINQ anyway.